Ender 3 Pro & NeoV2 thermal warning on boot
Ive been using an Ender 3 Pro and Neo V2 as work horse machines. Both recently needed hot end replacements.
I ordered official parts. The Neo V2 came first, I installed the hot end according to instructions. On boot, the printer immediately tells me I've got a hotend overheat...that's not even possible.
I got all the parts for my Pro as I decided to use this as a chance to upgrade the motherboard as well. Same issue. Immediately after boot thermal runaway warning kicks in.
With the pro I tried replacing the thermimstor, same issue.
I'm now well behind on my work load and have 2 dead machines. Can anyone please offer help.

This appears to be a similar question as Ender 3 Thermal Runaway Error when booting up. You have changed the thermistor, but did you over-tighten this? This is most probably a shorting thermistor. Please check your wiring.

On the NeoV2 it turned out the factory tightened thermistor was too tight, so thanks for that one. I've checked the pro's thermistors and both had minor wire breaks, so replaced and that's all good now.
